# Setting the initial toolbar title based on ViewPager on startup

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar

This is a variant on a familiar problem (such as this: [Setting action bar title in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847194/setting-action-bar-title-in-viewpager))

I have a ViewPager setup in my main activity. The ViewPager is set to represent a date. I've set it up with an `OnPageChangeListener` and `onPageListener` to set the toolbar title to a given date (the default on startup being the current date). `onPageListener` is called, but *some other event is called afterwards*, and it sets the toolbar title *back* to the defined app name. Even setting it explicitly in the activity's `onCreate` doesn't fix the title, it is still replaced by the app name.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Date _displayedDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new DatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                _displayedDate = DateUtils.offsetDate(position);
                showDisplayedDate(); // no apparent effect
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        _displayedDate = new Date();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem((int)DateUtils.getDayOffset(_displayedDate));
        showDisplayedDate();  // no apparent effect
    }

    public void showDisplayedDate() {
        if (_displayedDate != null) {
            toolbar.setTitle(_displayedDate.toString())); // simplified version of date display
        }
    }
}

public class DatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
```

So, what gives? How do I set the title based on the ViewPager's initial display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648227/remove-title-in-toolbar-in-appcompat-v7v21), this removes the automatic app title in the toolbar, and the rest of the logic takes care of displaying the date:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```